# Bash - alternative for: ls | grep

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, grep, ls

I use the following pipe as variable in a script:

```
match=$( ls | grep -i "$search")
```

this is then used in an *if statement*:

```
if [ "$match" ]; then
    echo "matches found"
else
    echo "no matches found"
fi
```

what would be an alternative if I did not want to use find?
[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) recommends:

> ls /directory/target_file_pattern

but I do not get the syntax right to get the same result.
also I want *no output* when there are no matches for the *if statement* to work.

Comment: Why would you ever *not* want to use `find`? This is what it's good at.

Comment: I did not want to do a recursive search and the code to be rather simple, I love find, but I could not be convinced to use finds `-maxdepth`

Comment: Use ls pathtofile > /dev/null 2> &1 then use the exit status I.e. $? In your if statement.

Comment: @RamanSailopal better `test -f` in that case, but I don't think he's even figured out the difference between globs, BREs, and EREs yet.

Comment: On further thought, this question probably doesn't have enough info to answer- we'd need to know what the pattern looks like.

Comment: @RamanSailopal that does not help, I need to get my `"$search"` somewhere, I truied `ls patthtofile/*$search*` but I could not get that working propperly, though  the redirection to `/dev/null` is a good idea, I might use this, If I do not end up using find in the end.

Comment: Should work fine. Are you sure you are using Bash?

Comment: @o11c _I don't think he's even figured out the difference between globs, BREs, and EREs yet._ maybe you want to share your knowledge, write an answer and get some credits :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to tell if there exist any matches with `bash` you could use the builtin `compgen` like so:

```
if compgen -G 'glob_pattern_like_your_grep' >/dev/null; then
    echo "matches found"
else
    echo "no matches found"
fi
```

if you want to operate on the files that are matched, `find` is usually the right tool for the job:

```
find . -name 'glob_pattern_like_your_grep' -exec 'your command to operate on each file that matches'
```

the key though is that you have to use [glob patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns), not regex type patterns.

If your `find` supports it, you might be able to match a regex like

```
find . -regex 'pattern'
```

and use that in either the `if` or with `-exec`

Comment: Note that, depending on your exact input, `compgen` can be *very* slow (as in, I have a case where it takes about a minute for something `grep` can handle instantaneously).

Comment: Is there a portable alternative to `compgen` in sh or any other POSIX shell, I just want to check if any file match the given pattern exist

Comment: @jimmymcheung I don't know of one off the top of my head.  The `find` command varieties should be portable though.  Adding a `-maxdepth 1` would restrict the match to the current directory if that's all you want to look at.

Comment: Would there be a performance penalty with `find`? Each time when I run `find` on my personal computer it is pretty slow. Honestly I don't really understand why `ls | grep` is not recommended but I want to avoid security risk and keep the performance as good as possible. @EricRenouf

Comment: @jimmymcheung often times it's possible to get away with parsing `ls` output, but it can go wrong, and is often a sign that things might be fragile or not handle unexpected cases well.  One of the commonly sited writes ups is at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and a sister site has a long discussion about it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead.  `find` will often be much slower, especially if you have a lot of directories it decends into which the globs would ignore.  That's why I suggested the maxdepth flag for example

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`:

```
match="$(find . -path "*${search}*" -printf "." | wc -c)"
```

`$match` will contain the number of matches. You can check it like this:

```
if [ "${match}" -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "${match} files found"
else
    echo "No files found"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really nice solution too, I'll accept Eric Renouf answer for bringing up something non find related and the explanation with glob and regex type patterns. But definitely an up-vote!

Comment: how would the `find` command need to look like if it was using `-regex` instead of `-path`?

Comment: if `$search` is a valid regex (check the find manpage for that) it's just `-regex "${search}"` instead of `-path`